# Can we ask questions related to E-Commerce here?

Tags: discussion

As we know magento is an E-commerce platform and user might ask related questions. I can only one new proposed site in stackexchange is directly related to E-commerce. Should we not classify such question as off topic until E-commerce launch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question!  I think this is exactly the kind of thing we're going to have to iron out here in order to make this site truly useful and tailored to the Magento world.

I would say that if it does not relate directly to Magento in some way, it shouldn't be allowed.  So for example a question like:

[What's the average profit margin earned by eCommerce retailers?](http://www.quora.com/E-Commerce/Whats-the-average-Profit-Margin-earned-by-apparel-distributors-Brick-Mortar-Retailers-E-Commerce-Online-Retailers)

I don't think should be allowed.  Although we all care a lot about eCommerce, I think part of the reason we should be strict with this is that opening up this site to all things Magento (merchant-facing, developer-facing, marketing-facing) already casts a pretty wide net, so we'll need to be careful not to dilute it too much.

Comment: Yes, the primary focus of the question should relate to Magento directly. Keep that laser-tight focus on your subject. The scope of this site should not extend too much into other more-generic subjects which just *happen* to share a common interest in this community. This site is about the *subject* of Magento and related modules. It cannot reasonably become a place to ask more generalized e-commerse or other industry-related questions.

Comment: @Robert Agreed - this Magento SE, not eCommerce SE.

Comment: Though I would love to see a question regarding the query within Magento to calculate our average profit margin...

Comment: Funny thing is, I totally just asked a question yesterday that would probably fall under this category: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4064/issue-management-protocols-for-merchant-teams - haha didn't even realize it when I posted it.